# Does Pyomo5.5 support gurobi7.5 or gurobi8.0 directly?

Tags: pyomo

I want to use pyomo5.5 to call solver gurobi7.5 or gurobi8.0, but found that it returns error when call the solver directly.

If I use gurobi_ampl7.5 or 8.0, it will work.

So, does that mean pyomo5.5 can't support to call gurobi directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Pyomo to call Gurobi directly (through the python interface), the package `gurobipy` needs to be importable from the python environment in which Pyomo is running.

Try following the Python interface installation instructions from the Gurobi website: http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/quickstart_mac/the_gurobi_python_interfac.html